# How to specify an input with a list of arrays to Embedding layer in Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, word2vec, word-embedding

I'm trying to do some word-level text generation and stuck with the foloowing problem:

My input looks like this:

```py
   tokenized_seq = [[w2v_model.wv.vocab[word].index for word in w2v_data[i]] for i in range(len(w2v_data))]
   x_seq = []
   y_seq = []

   for seq in tokenized_seq:
      x_seq.append(seq[:-1])
      y_seq.append([seq[-1]])
```

So, I'm going along the sequence (encoded words usnig word2vec) with the rolling window of the fixed size (tokenized _seq is a list of sequence with fixed length).

Look the example:

Code block:

```py
print(x_seq[0], '->', y_seq[0])  
print(' '.join([w2v_model.wv.index2word[i] for i in x_seq[0]]), '->', w2v_model.wv.index2word[y_seq[0].pop()])
```

Output:

```
[608, 1661, 1, 4260, 1, 3, 2978, 741, 0, 153, 740, 1, 12004] -> [109]
часть первая . i . — eh bien , mon prince . gênes -> et
```

So, then, I'm trying to input all above to Embedding layer.

```py
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(input_dim=vocab_size,
                    output_dim=emdedding_size,
                    input_length=avg_sent_len-1,
                    weights=[predtrained_weights]
                    trainable=False))

model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(units=128)))

model.add(Dense(units=vocab_size, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(x_seq, y_seq,
                   epochs=10,
                   batch_size=128,
                   validation_split=0.2,
                   verbose=2)
```

Embedding parameters are:

```
predtrained_weights = w2v_model.wv.vectors
vocab_size, emdedding_size = w2v_model.wv.vectors.shape
```

`avg_sent_len` is the len of each seqence in `x_seq`

The model compiles well, but when fitting I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_40 to have shape (31412,) but got array with shape (223396,)
```

(31412,) is `vocab_size`
223396 is `x_seq` or `y_seq` length (number of input sequences)
So, could anybody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You input `x_seq` should be one numpy array of shape `(batch_size, seq_len)`. Try adding `x_seq = np.array(x_seq)`.

Comment: Thanks, this helped, but i still has problems with embedding input. It expects input to be in shape of  `vocab_size`, but the input provied (and i think, this is the right way) is `x_seq.shape` which is not the same. So I'm a bit confused

Comment: Probably the problem is with the BiLSTM layer following your embedding layer. The `input_shape` of that layer should be `(seq_len, embedding_size)`, not `(vocab_size, seq_len)` as you wrote in your code. If this doesn't help then please provide the error message that you get.

Comment: I've tryed to use both unspecified LSTM: `model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(units=128))`l ike in a bunch examples and specify input shape as you said: `model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(units=128, input_shape=(len(x_seq), emdedding_size))))` Anf both ways didnt help. An error message i get: `ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_34 to have shape (31412,) but got array with shape (223396,)` *31412,* is vocab size, *223396* - length of `x_seq` (input)

Comment: This error is a problem with the targets (`y_seq`), not the inputs (`x_seq`). Your target should have shape `(batch_size, vocab_size)` where each of the rows is one hot encoded. And you can indeed just leave out the `input_shape` of the LSTM layer.

Comment: If you use `categorical_crossentropy` as loss your labels should definitely be one hot encoded. Alternatively you can use `sparse_categorical_crossentropy`. In this case your labels should have shape `(batch_size, 1)` and *not* be one hot encoded. For example the following dummy data will work with sparse categorical crossentropy: `x_seq = np.random.rand(n_samples, seq_len)` and `y_seq = np.random.randint(0, vocab_size, n_samples).reshape((-1,1))`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It was really my bad, using `catigorical_crossetrpy` instead of `sparse_categorical_crossentropy`. After just adding *sparse* preffix to activation function everything everything worked well